# How to stop the execution of a script after some number of edits?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

The script below executes well to get the category names from a Wikipedia page. How to stop after 10 minutes or after getting 100 categories?

The code bellow needs the above said limitation:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import time

#getting all the contents of a url
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free software'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

#showing the category-pages Summary
catPageSummaryTag = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
catPageSummary = catPageSummaryTag.find('p')
print(catPageSummary.text)

#showing the category-pages only
catPageSummaryTag = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
tag = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
links = tag.findAll('a')

#getting the category pages
catpages = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
whatlinksherelist = catpages.find_all('li')
things_to_write = []
for titles in whatlinksherelist:
  things_to_write.append(titles.find('a').get('title'))
  WAIT_TIME = 15
  print(titles.text)
  time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)  
#writing the category pages as a output file
with open('001-catPages.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter="\n")
  writer.writerow(things_to_write)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this in your programe:-**

```
#showing the category-pages only
catPageSummaryTag = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
tag = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
links = tag.findAll('a')
catpages = soup.find(id='mw-pages')
whatlinksherelist = catpages.find_all('li')
things_to_write = []
count = 0  #mentioned to count till 100
for titles in whatlinksherelist:
    if count<=100:
        things_to_write.append(titles.find('a').get('title'))
        count+=1
        print(titles.text)

#writing the category pages as a output file
with open('001-catPages.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter="\n")
  writer.writerow(things_to_write)
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop the code or any code after a particular time?

Comment: Instead of stop get result as 100 categories and exit from program. it's same like you want this result and let me exit from there... right.

Comment: Or you can make function for this and give option expected result let say 50 so whenever it completes condition it will exit from program.

Comment: Few months before i started learning programme. Will you pls guide me which py-function, i have to learn for the stop?

Comment: For example, i need to do 1000 edits in Wikipedia. My script is doing find and replace task. If it stops, after 10 minutes, i can check those completed pages. Then i can change the code re-run.

Comment: for specific condition you can give  a= time.time() which will give you current time later you can subtract by another time() or in function you can pass it to make stop (although it's not in good practice)....